# Host Firebase/React web application on a Raspberry Pi

Tags: node.js, reactjs, raspberry-pi, web-deployment, raspberry-pi4

I have created a web application to process and store input data using Firebase/React.
Usually on my local machine I simply use `npm start` to start the web application and access it via Phone or Tablet over my IPv4 number.

What would be the best way to host it locally on a Raspberry Pi (v.4 with Raspbian installed), taking into consideration:

1. In best case I only want to start it once and then it should run forever, even when it gets accidentally restarted (I think I need a Daemon for that (?))
2. The webapp should be only accessible for users within the same network. How can I make sure to select a constant local IP, that won't change over time ?

I hope I could make my case clear and would appreciate any advice!
Best Regards

Answer (score 2):

I would use Apache web server to turn the Raspberry Pi into a webserver. I would imagine the process would follow these steps

1. [Configure Apache](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/remote-access.html#setting-up-an-apache-web-server) on your Raspberry Pi
2. run `npm run build` from your react project
3. Copy the "build" directory contents to `/var/www/html/` on your raspberry Pi
4. [Configure the network interface](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/configuration.html#static-ip-addresses) with a static IP address

The raspberry Pi's network address is is the IP address you would use to access the web server served by  Apache on the local network

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Sounds like a plan. What about the static IP address?

Comment: Sure. I did mention in the answer that you would need to configure the network interface. I added a link. For reference, its [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/tcpip/). Remember that the Pie is acting as the web server, so its own network IP address will be the address of the website served by Apache on the local network. Best to get the web server running first using DHCP, and then try to configure a static IP address.

Comment: I am will try right now and get back to you. Thansk a lot !